# Codeigniter db select

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to select products from my table where is Akcie 1 and Stav also 1. But it it search query so I have there more like. It is not working why? Here is query

```
$q = $this->db->where('Akcia', 1)
          ->like('Titul', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('PodTitul', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('Autor1', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('Autor2', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('Autor3', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('Autor4', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('Prekladatel', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('Rozmer', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('Vydavatelstvo', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('ISBN', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('EAN', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('Popis', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('KratkyPopis', $vyraz)
      ->or_like('RokVydania', $vyraz)
      ->where('stav', 1)
      ->order_by('id', 'desc')
      ->limit($limit)
      ->offset($offset)
     ->get('knihy');

         return $q->result();
```

This query is selcting also pruduts where Akcia is 0 why?

Answer (score 1):

Well if I am correct the code will produce this condition on the SQL :

```
WHERE Akcia = 1 AND Titul LIKE 'param' OR PodTitul LIKE 'param' etc.
```

so if any of the "or_like" param get a hit, automatically your condition for the Akcia will be disregarded and the system will still show all records whether they have 1 or 0 value

what you need is to include a parenthesis like this:

```
WHERE Akcia = 1 AND (Titul LIKE 'param' OR PodTitul LIKE 'param' etc.)
```

I think this is what you need, refer to this link :

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/105664/#548079